# Every other call to Async WCF is slow

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, asynchronous

I'm using code examples from this article by Rick Strahl: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx to make async calls to a WCF service, which works just great.

**My problem is this:**
First call to the WCF Service takes in the vicinity of 20ms, whereas the next takes around 1sec 20ms (doing exactly the same and receiving the exact same data). If I repeat the process the result is the same all the time. Every other call takes one second longer than the first.

I've tried setting the InstanceContextMode on my service:

```
  [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public abstract class AjaxPostBack : IAjaxPostBack
```

I've also set timers in the methods being called on the service, and the result is the same every time (of course some ms differences, but nothing significant)

```
"JSON_Took":"00:00:00.0012939","Set_took":"00:00:00.0000274"
```

(These values - JSON_Took & Set_took - are timers in the code behind methods. So not the total time from client-server-client. It's simply to illustrate that it's not a problem with the actual code being timeconsuming)

Any ideas?

Let me know if you need more information.

---- **Interesting Update** ----

I downloaded IE9 RC and also Firefox (I've been testing in Chrome)
My results from the different browsers:

**Firefox**: All calls are consistent at approx ~1s 20ms to 1s 30ms

**Chrome**: Every other call fires at the speed of Firefox, and the rest at 1 second quicker

**IE9**: All calls are consistent at virtually no time at all (~20ms)

**Opera**: Pretty much the same as IE9 (~30ms)

Is this a webkit-issue? (I'm using $.ajax to call the WCF)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I can offer this: try turning on WCF tracing and see if anything shiny comes up.  Turn on tracing for `"System.ServiceModel"`

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that.. Not that it solved anything, but I've done some more experimenting, and it seems that it's a browser-issue.. I'm updating my question..

Comment: Hmmm.  Well, there's Wireshark.  But it likely won't provide you with anything new.

Comment: Is this IIS or the Visual Studio dev server?

Comment: I'm confused by your times.  When you say the slow call takes "1sec 20ms", do you actually mean `1.20ms`, and when you say the fast call takes "20ms", do you actually mean `20µs`?  Those are the times shown in the `JSON_Took:` line.

Comment: Its the VS2010 devserver... I mean 1020 milliseconds when i say 1sec 20ms and I mean 20 milliseconds when i say 20ms. The Json_took is just the code behind method whereas the summarytimes are from the client fires till it gets data back.

Comment: I wouldn't depend on timings from the devserver.  What happens if you deploy your service to IIS (or even IIS Express)?  The VS2010 DevServer isn't as reliable of a server for timings and won't be a good indicator for production performance.

Comment: Also, is your `$.ajax` call pretty standard, or are you doing anything out of the ordinary?  Doing any caching, setting non-standard content types, handling any events, etc.?  Also, is your `$.ajax` call returning a successful call, or is an error being generated?  If errors are being thrown, that will definitely consume some CPU.

Comment: @David Hoerster - You were absolutely right. The problem went away when I deployed to a regular IIS. Still weird that the issue was only with Chrome.. Haven't figured that out yet... Post your comment as an answer if you want me to accept it :)

Comment: I added it and also included a link to a good article discussing the differences b/w IIS and the VS Web Server -- it may help others going forward.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't depend on timings from the devserver. What happens if you deploy your service to IIS (or even IIS Express)? The VS2010 DevServer isn't as reliable of a server for timings and won't be a good indicator for production performance.

[Here's a good article](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/core-differences-between-iis-and-the-asp-net-development-server-cs) (although slightly dated) discussing the differences between IIS and the Visual Studio Web Server (aka Cassini).

Glad this helps!